# Failed inspection on because of OBD2 readiness

Tags: obd-ii, hyundai, emissions

My 2008 Hyundai failed inspection because the OBD-II system is in a "not ready" state.  The mechanic asked if my battery had died recently. It had, after getting an alignment. He suggested driving on the highway for 60 miles or so. After doing this I got tested again and failed again.

He said I had one final chance to pass. I have 5 days left on my temporary inspection paper. What can I do? Take my car to a dump if it fails again?

Comment: See page 5 of http://epa.ohio.gov/portals/27/echeck/docs/Comprehensive_OBD_ReadinessInfo.pdf.  If someone wants to expand this into a full answer they are welcome to do so .

Comment: We have no idea what the inspection laws are in your jurisdiction (you didn't even say what your jurisdiction is) but it's very unlikely you'd be required to junk your car if it doesn't pass.  More likely you'd be required to have it fixed - which might mean paying the mechanic to do the necessary drive cycle.

Comment: It's very unlikely that you will be immediately prohibited from driving the car on test failure. You should have a certain period of time to do whatever is necessary to fix the problem and re-take the test. Beyond that, some states have maximum repair costs for emissions-related problems, and you can get a waiver if the situation is serious enough. Look at your state DMV/RMV site, or scan [AAA's list of state-by-state summaries](http://drivinglaws.aaa.com/laws/emissions-inspection/).

Comment: I must say, Inspection is very important. OBD reader will helpful for you.

Answer (score 3):

Every car's OBDII diagnostic is going to be slightly different (between manufacturers, anyway), but you should not be dismayed. You have five days until you fail your test, which is more than enough time to ensure your vehicle will be OBDII ready. This of course, does not mean if there is an underlying problem it won't cause you to fail for a different reason (like a bad cat or something). With that said, ensure you are driving your vehicle every day until you can take it back for the retest. When you drive it, ensure you run the vehicle up to operating temperature and then drive it for several miles (10-20 miles) to ensure the system is doing it's self checks. If you give it several days, it will reset. If you want to have it checked before you take it to the station, you can take it to an AutoZone, Advance Auto, or the like. If you do take it to a place like that to have them check the status, **ENSURE THEY DO NOT RESET THE SYSTEM!!** If they do, you'll be back to square one.

It just takes a little time and a few system cycles. The key here is to run the car to fully warm, drive for a while, then allow it to fully cool before you go on your next drive. You can do several of these in a day and get to a "good" state sooner.

Answer (score 2):

To perform an OBDII Driving cycle do the following: Cold Start. In order to be classified as a cold start the engine coolant temperature must be below 50°C (122°F) and within 6°C (11°F) of the ambient air temperature at startup. Do not leave the key on prior to the cold start or the heated oxygen sensor diagnostic may not run. Idle. The engine must be run for two and a half minutes with the air conditioner on and rear defroster on. The more electrical load you can apply the better. This will test the O2 heater, Passive Air, Purge "No Flow", Misfire and if closed loop is achieved, Fuel Trim. Accelerate. Turn off the air conditioner and all the other loads and apply half throttle until 88km/hr (55mph) is reached. During this time the Misfire, Fuel Trim, and Purge Flow diagnostics will be performed. Hold Steady Speed. Hold a steady speed of 88km/hr (55mph) for 3 minutes. During this time the O2 response, air Intrusive, EGR, Purge, Misfire, and Fuel Trim diagnostics will be performed. Decelerate. Let off the accelerator pedal. Do not shift, touch the brake or clutch. It is important to let the vehicle coast along gradually slowing down to 32km/hr (20 mph). During this time the EGR, Purge and Fuel Trim diagnostics will be performed. Accelerate. Accelerate at 3/4 throttle until 88-96 km/hr (55-60mph). This will perform the same diagnostics as in step 3. Hold Steady Speed. Hold a steady speed of 88km/hr (55mph) for five minutes. During this time, in addition to the diagnostics performed in step 4, the catalyst monitor diagnostics will be performed. If the catalyst is marginal or the battery has been disconnected, it may take 5 complete driving cycles to determine the state of the catalyst. Decelerate. This will perform the same diagnostics as in step 5. Again, don't press the clutch or brakes or shift gears. Reprinted  courtesy of General Motors Corporation  While this is sourced by GM I believe it is applicable to all OBD II vehicles

Answer (score 0):

Buy an ODB reader for $40 and find out if your car pass before taking it to get it officially inspected.